# Find file in "changes made" in TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have done a lot of changes locally, around 1000 files. Is there some search box to filter the list in TortoiseSVN?

[image: showing count]

Comment: in the search box on top in svn log you can type a name of a file and it gets highlighted in red in lower part of the dialog

Comment: But I am having the commit open dialog here.

Comment: in this case there is no search window . why do you want to search here for a file?

Comment: Because I have so many modified files, but only want to commit a few.

Comment: you can use your file manager to open a subfolder and open here the check for mod files, add it to a [changelist](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html) and if you added all files, open check for mod files in root and select the files from changelist to commit them.